# Upload and set facet on the same onedrive upload request?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I want to use my onedrive as a document storage.
Each document should have some meta info associated so that I can search for them by using apis. So, suppose each document has a "student" and "age" associated meta.

According to the documentation I have to:

1. Make a PUT request against the OneDrive to upload my item
2. Make a PATCH request against the item, by providing a facet I previously created

Would it to be possible to create AND patch my item without having to make two request? It doesn't seem very intuitive to me...

Answer (score 0):

Each action (uploading a `DriveItem` and updating a `DriveItem` record) requires a separate call to Microsoft Graph.

Considering the payload for your upload (`PUT`) is the binary content of the file, where would a developer deliver the JSON payload to update the metadata (`PATCH`)?